# Add values to a column of dataframe based on the common values with a column of another dataframe

Tags: r

I have the 2 datasets below:

```
stud<-c("MARK","DGHN","BHKJ")
mark<-c(4,6,7)
d1<-data.frame(stud,mark)

stud2<-c("MARK","DGHN","BHKJ","dfgd","fg")
mark2<-""
d2<-data.frame(stud2,mark2)
```

I want to pass to the `mark2` of `d2` the values of `mark` of `d1` for the students that exist in both `stud` and `stud2`. The rest of the names of the `stud2` should remain as they are but their respective `mark2` values should be `NAs`.I tried:

```
d2$stud2 <- factor(d2$stud2, levels=levels(d1$stud))
d2$mark2 <- ifelse(d2$stud2 == d1$stud, d1$mark, NA)
```

but not all of the `stud2` values appear. Is there another way without having to mess with the fact that they do not have the same count of factors?